# HTML, CSS - Меню

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Доброй день, друзья. Интересует вопрос касательно меню. Имеются 2 проблемы при его верстке:

1. До сих пор не могу понять кому я должен назначать стили и какие. Поясню:
   собственно на макете вы увидите как оформляется меню, вопрос в том: кому назначать падинги, задний фон, бордер сверху? Ссылке или лишке?
2. Попытался импровизировать, но возникла следующая проблема. Бордер сверху над пунктом меню должен быть статичным при наведении на кнопочку, но проблема в том, что после того как срабатывает :hover, этот бордер толкает все меню вниз.

Буду благодарен за любые советы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: применяете своей ссылке a{border: 1px solid transparent} затем a:hover{border: 1px solid red}

Comment: То есть задать ссылке нужно прозрачный border-top? Как я понял и ей же нужно задавать padding?

Comment: border-top да; мой ответ про 2 вопрос

Comment: Так код и не нужен, описания вопроса достаточно, чтоб представить себе эту картину, + первый вопрос это сугубо теоретическая составляющая.

Comment: О каком коде идет речь??? Это скрин из макета, я не понимаю как его сверстать (не понимаю какие стили применять), поэтому и задаю вопросы. Я ничего не могу предложить кроме скрина АЛЛО. А в нете можно найти много чего лишнего. Зачем? Когда тут знающие сидят, могут что подсказать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получите ваше меню и распишитесь:

```css
nav {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 2px 10px 0 10px;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 12px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

a:before,
a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: skyblue;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

a:before {
  left: 0;
}

a:after {
  right: 0;
}

li:hover a:before {
  width: 50%;
}

li:hover a:after {
  width: 50%;
}

li:hover a {
  color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вариант при помощи **`border-top`**.

Суть в чём, изначально `border-top` есть, но его не видно, ибо его цвет `transparent` (прозрачный), при наведение он становится нужным цветом. Эффект затухания\появления.

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 12px 10px; /* 7px - это верхний отступ, он как и нижний 10px - 3px бордера сверху */
  background: #e8ebf1;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  font-size: 140%;
}

.item:hover {
  border-top-color: #2aacc8;
  color: #2aacc8;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Наведи на меня</div>
```

В принципе, можно сделать эффект "выезда", через `border-top`, но при анимации мы будет наблюдать дёрганье:

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background: #e8ebf1;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 0 solid #2aacc8;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  font-size: 140%;
}

.item:hover {
  border-top-width: 3px;
  padding-top: 7px; /* те же 10px - 3px */
  color: #2aacc8;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Наведи на меня</div>
```

---

По этому, считаю, что для реализации нужной вам фишки, лучше всего использовать **`box-shadow`**.
К тому же не придётся трогать `padding` вообще, ибо `box-shadow` идёт от границ элемента и по факту игнорирует отступы.

Эффект затухания\появления:

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background: #e8ebf1;
  color: #000;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  font-size: 140%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 transparent inset;
}

.item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #2aacc8 inset;
  color: #2aacc8;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Наведи на меня</div>
```

Эффект "выезда":

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background: #e8ebf1;
  color: #000;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  font-size: 140%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #2aacc8 inset;
}

.item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #2aacc8 inset;
  color: #2aacc8;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Наведи на меня</div>
```